# How can i run psiphon-tunnel-core.exe in my vb code as a background process?

Tags: vb.net

I'm building my own vpn and would like to integrate Psiphon-tunnel-core.exe and keep it alive. I would like my programs to tunnel through it once I click start so that it works like a vpn. But when I start the process it immediately flashes a cmd screen and disappears. im using this code to start the process.

```
Process.Start("C:\Users\Alma Tech\AppData\Local\Temp\psiphon-tunnel-core.exe")
```

Any help?